# jQuery check to test contents of an iframe not triggering

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an iframe form embedded in a page on a site. This gets blocked in browsers that disabled third party cookies, which is fine.

What I want to do, is display a message and a link to another page if an error page is displayed within the iframe, which is what happens when third party cookies are blocked.

This is what I have at the moment, which I think should work (the error page contains the text being searched for), but the element I am trying to hide is never hidden.

```
<html>
<body>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
  
<a href="#" id="testlink">Test text</a>

<iframe src="https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html" width="100%"  height="80%" frameborder="0" scrolling="0"></iframe>

<script>
  var x = document.getElementById("testlink");
  if($("iframe").contents().text().search("General Public License") > -1) {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
  x.style.display = "none";
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code shown runs before the elements exist

Comment: @charlietfl that's not it. moving code after makes no difference. Will edit question to reflect.

Comment: Try using iframe load event handler also to access contents. If browser is blocking and causing error page my guess is you can't get inside it also

Comment: @charlietfl Can you give an example? The browser is not giving any error, the error page is from the web application within the iframe when it detects cookies are disabled. It's a server side error message.

Comment: `$("myiframe").on('load', function(){ /* look for contents */})`

Comment: @charlietfl I haven't been able to get anything working. If you have a solution and want to post it as an answer I would happily accept it as correct.

Comment: In dev tools console network tab what is `status` of the error page...is it a 200 or 400-500 series?

Comment: @charlietfl it's 200 series, like I said the error message is not a real error, it's a message displayed by the webapp entirely server side. Everything is functioning as it should. The webapp checks if it can set a cookie and if it can't it displays a different page, that's all.

Comment: And page and frame are same origin? Try `$("myiframe").contents().find('body").text()`

Comment: Ohhhhhhh..missing `#` for id selector `$("#myiframe")`

Comment: @charlietfl Changing to .find('body').text didn't work at all, and adding the # doesn't seem to have made a difference.

Comment: Am out of ideas without being able to see it in action and see what's happening in dev tools

Comment: @charlietfl You can just copy the code to a local html file. You can use anything for the iframe src. The problem is searching for text within an iframe. It isn't specific the particular page I am using.

Comment: Well here's an example I know that works https://plnkr.co/edit/W01O5tXB9ThdATTS?preview Different operation but same concept

Comment: @charlietfl I changed the example code in the question to one referencing the GPL page, so anyone can copy it to a local file and test it. Otherwise thanks for your attempts so far.

Comment: That won't work since is a different origin and can't access cross origin iframe

Comment: @charlietfl So you are saying there is no way to search for text within a cross origin iframe?

Comment: Correct... browser blocks access for security reasons. I assumed your 2 apps were on same origin.